# How to handle database exceptions in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, exception, connection

I'm using Oracle through their official managed drivers for .NET (a Nuget package).

My application uses the same connection to the DB from the beginning and it's used from several locations to perform queries.

In some cases, there may be connection "hiccups" that cause exceptions. The problem is that I don't know what's the best strategy to retry to perform a query when this happens.

Is there a common way to solve this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: The is pretty broad, but why are you using a single connection, why not use multiple connections and open connection as late as possible and close as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from Habib.

The oracle .NET Package uses connection pooling.  Even if you open up multiple connections, it will manage them accordingly so that you don't have to keep it open.

That means that your code can be simplified, into something like this pseudo-code:

```
using(OracleConnection conn = MakeConnection())
{
   //do stuff with connection

   //not necessary, but I always manually close connection. Doesn't hurt.
   conn.Close();
}
```

If you're uncertain of connection issues even in that small of an execution, you can wrap it in a try-catch block like so:

```
try
{
   using(OracleConnection conn = MakeConnection())
   {
      //do stuff with connection

      //not necessary, but I always manually close connection. Doesn't hurt.
      conn.Close();
   }
}
catch(OracleException ex)
{
    //handle exception.
}
```

OracleException looks to be the main exception with the .NET oracle package.  Please note that there may be others you want to catch more specifically.

Comment: `Using` block will take care of Connection.Close() and Connection.Dispose()  usually , even in case of exceptions. We need not specify it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to instantiate the connection on the fly when the query is being made. I don't think a simple try/catch would help you here because even if you reinitialized the connection in the catch block, you would have to somehow re-execute your query.

I don't recommend this but you could use a Retry class that reinitializes the connection if an exception is caught....

```
public class Retry
{
    public static void Do(Action action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        Do<object>(() =>
        {
            action();
            return null;
        }, 
        retryInterval, retryCount);
    }

    public static T Do<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (retry > 0)
                    Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
                return action();
            }
            catch (ConnectionException ex)
            {
                // ***Handle the reconnection in here***

                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }

        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Then you can call your query like

```
Retry.Do(() => MyQueryMethod, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

I got the basis for this Retry code from SO a long time ago, don't recall the thread but it isn't my original code. I have used it quite a bit for some things though.